# Can copper sulfate react with terpenes (such as limonene and terpinenes) at room temperature?

Tags: coordination-compounds, transition-metals, organometallic-compounds

I am just wondering, can I make a metalorganic or organometallic complex of copper and limonene/terpinene/phellandrene in the form of lime oil? If so, what is the formula of the complex formed? I tried the reaction with lime oil in iPrOH, and a copper sulfate solution. The result was a blue crystalline solid. What are the crystals? I'd like to know.

Comment: I have a video of the reaction that I performed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PeJhFKj1nuw

Comment: By the way, the compound is an opaque blue solid, and I used iPrOH to dissolve and extract the terpenes, as well as to wash the crystals.

Comment: The terpenes in the oil, I mean. It's poorly soluble in water, and insoluble in iPrOH.

Comment: Most of the evidence you present, together with solubility data from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper(II)_sulfate), seems consistent with just precipitating the copper sulfate.  Note that because of spectrochemical effects, we would expect the complex to change color if organic ligands were to displace water.

Comment: Yes there is nothing in terpenes to coordinate with copper ion. You got copper sulfate again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, after M. Farook's agreement I am making my comment an answer.

Most of the evidence you present, together with solubility data from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper(II)_sulfate), seems consistent with just precipitating the copper sulfate. Note that because of spectrochemical effects, we would expect the complex to change color if organic ligands were to displace water.